# How can I implement a linear mixed model on data where the reference doesn't have repeated measures?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design, lasso, glmmlasso

I want to analyze in paired data that has many dependent variables (continuous) and several categorical predictors. The predictors are: Group (patient/control), Treatment (none, t1, t2, t3), and Gene (several). The issue is that the treatments were not applied to all samples, so that controls received no treatment and therefore have only one observation, while patients received one or two of the treatments.

I believe the only approach that could work is (generalized) linear mixed models, which I'm learning about now. What I can't figure out is how exactly to implement it. My goals are to find molecules that have significantly different concentrations in patients vs. controls, see if the treatment/s significantly alter those concentrations in patients, and see if those alteration makes the patients more similar to the controls.

I though of using something like lasso or hypothesis testing to first identify molecules that are altered between the controls and the patients before they received treatments and then use linear mixed models to see if the treatments changed those molecule concentrations. I'm not sure if that's correct or if I would be introducing bias, maybe I should instead compare models that include different predictors? But then I wouldn't know how to identify which molecules were affected. Or should I make one model for each molecule and see which predictors contribute to it's variation?